# Printing embeded PDFs in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So I think Chrome and Firefox interpretation of DOM is screwing with me. I am trying to print a pdf from a browser (dynamically created) because I can't have the header and footer normally printed with printing an HTML page. Now I was just sending the PDF using fpdf from a php page and use the toolbar or right click and print but now the clients want a button on the page to initiate the print dialog but of course not print anything else but the PDF.... so I embeded it:

```
    <embed
        type="application/pdf"
        src="print_pdf.php"
        id="pdfDocument"
        width="100%"
        height="100%" />
```

and a button's onClick called

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function printDocument(documentId) {

        ((function(){return document.getElementById(documentId);})()).print();


        //Wait until PDF is ready to print    
        if (typeof document.getElementById(documentId).print == 'undefined') {

            setTimeout(function(){printDocument(documentId);}, 1000);

        } else {

            var x = document.getElementById(documentId);
            x.print();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

where documentID = "pdfDocument"

This worked great in IE9 but chrome and mozilla all say "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'print'"

so I tried to use  thinking embed was causing improper object interpretation in chrome:

```
<object data="print_pdf.php" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" id="pdfD2">
```

alt : test.pdf

and called the same onClick, where documentID = "pdfD2"... "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'print'"

Then I tried an Iframe:  
    ... "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'print'"

I'm so frustrated given Chrome is my go to... I even disabled chrome's builtin PDF view and used Adobe 10.xxx.. ARGH!!!

FYI, my simple button tags are:

```
<input type="button" value="Print Rx" onclick="printDocument('pdfDocument')">
<input type="button" value="Print Rx2" onclick="printDocument('pdfD2')">
<input type="button" value="Print Rx3" onclick="printDocument('pdfD3')">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the line:

```
((function(){return document.getElementById(documentId);})()).print();
```

which means that you "pack" (well possibly) uncompleted DOM into the closure.

It goes before the next line which checks for "undefined" print.

Apart from this, why do you use timeout, and not just use `onload` or `DOMReady` events?